# Incorrect Merge Sorting

Tags: java, string, sorting, merge

I'm working on a merge sorting program that sorts movies alphabetically by title. However, it is not sorting the list to completion. I have studied merge sorting, and looked at various other examples both on this site and elsewhere, and cannot find my error.

```
public static Movie4[] myMovies;

/**
 * printMovies traverses an array of movies and prints each respective title
 */
public static void printMovies(Movie4[] movies)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < movies.length; i ++)
    {
        System.out.println(movies[i]);
    }
}

/**
 * sortTitles sorts an array of movies alphabetically by title
 */
public static void sortTitles(Movie4[] movies, int low, int high)
{
    if (low == high)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Movie4[] firstHalf = new Movie4[movies.length  / 2];
        Movie4[] secondHalf = new Movie4[movies.length - movies.length / 2];
        int midpoint = (low + high) / 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < firstHalf.length; i ++)
        {
            firstHalf[i] = movies[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < secondHalf.length; i ++)
        {
            secondHalf[i] = movies[i + movies.length / 2];
        }
        sortTitles(firstHalf, low, midpoint);
        sortTitles(secondHalf, midpoint + 1, high);
        mergeTitles(movies, firstHalf, secondHalf);
    }
}

/**
 * mergeTitles works in conjunction with sortTitles to merge sort an array of Movie4 objects 
 */
public static void mergeTitles(Movie4[] movies, Movie4[] first, Movie4[] second)
{
    int i = 0;
    int i2 = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < movies.length; index ++)
    {
        if (i2 >= second.length || (i < first.length && 
                                        first[i].getTitle().compareTo(second[i2].getTitle()) < 0))
        {
            movies[index] = first[i];
            i ++;
        }
        else
        {
            movies[index] = second[i2];
            i2 ++;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    myMovies = new Movie4[10];
        myMovies[0] = new Movie4("The Muppets Take Manhattan", 2001, "Columbia Tristar");
        myMovies[1] = new Movie4("Mulan Special Edition", 2004, "Disney");
        myMovies[2] = new Movie4("Shrek 2", 2004, "Dreamworks");
        myMovies[3] = new Movie4("The Incredibles", 2004, "Pixar");
        myMovies[4] = new Movie4("Nanny McPhee", 2006, "Universal");
        myMovies[5] = new Movie4("The Curse of the Were-Rabbit", 2006, "Aardman");
        myMovies[6] = new Movie4("Ice Age", 2002, "20th Century Fox");
        myMovies[7] = new Movie4("Lilo and Stich", 2002, "Disney");
        myMovies[8] = new Movie4("Robots", 2005, "20th Century Fox");
        myMovies[9] = new Movie4("Monsters Inc.", 2001, "Pixar");

    System.out.println("Original List:");
    System.out.println();
    printMovies(myMovies);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("List Sorted by title, ascending:");
    System.out.println();
    sortTitles(myMovies, 0, myMovies.length - 1);
    printMovies(myMovies);
}
```

Please assume that the `getTitle()` method is defined elsewhere and simply returns the first `String` of each object, the title.
Here is the incorrect output;

```
List Sorted by title, ascending:

Ice Age, 2002, 20th Century Fox.
Lilo and Stich, 2002, Disney.
Mulan Special Edition, 2004, Disney.
Robots, 2005, 20th Century Fox.
Monsters Inc., 2001, Pixar.
Shrek 2, 2004, Dreamworks.
The Curse of the Were-Rabbit, 2006, Aardman.
The Incredibles, 2004, Pixar.
Nanny McPhee, 2006, Universal.
The Muppets Take Manhattan, 2001, Columbia Tristar.
```

I believe the error may be with my conditional statement, because if I set the `compareTo` value to > 0, it sorts correctly, just in the wrong order.

Comment: I would recommend learning to use a debugger.

Comment: Your code looks like an implementation of top-down [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). Did you consider the bottom-up approach? It feels more intuitive to me. I'd also implement the algorithm in terms of `[Comparable]` and would give `Movie4` a proper comparison method (one-liner).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be allocating new arrays or copying elements. Everything inside `sortTitles()` should be managed using `low` and `high`. Likewise, you should not be passing three arrays to `mergeTitles()`; instead, pass a single array and the values `low`, `midpoint` and `high` to let it know what parts of the array to merge.

Your current code seems to have a fencepost problem: you compute `midpoint` using `(low + high) / 2`, but use `movies.length / 2` for the length of the first array. Since `low` starts off as `0` and `high` starts off as `myMovies.length - 1`, these lengths will differ when `myMovies.length` is even. You may have other indexing problems, but I didn't look too deeply into that because the entire approach is flawed, as I described in the first paragraph.